# unpack binary file in python 3

Tags: python

Could you please help to unpack the binary file in Python 3? It is an image 2580*7839 size, 4-byte float. What I had in the code for Python 2 and it worked, but not in Python 3.

```
bformat= ">%sf"
ns = 2580*7839*4
#open file f
byte_arr=f.read(ns)
unpacked_bytes = unpack(bformat % (ns/4), byte_arr)
data=np.array(unpacked_bytes).reshape(7839,2580)
print ('min value', data.min())
print ('max value', data.max())
```

I get the error message "struct.error: bad char in struct format"

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a library like PIL for this?

Comment: because I need only the pixel values and then I work with arrays

Comment: But using `pixels = img.load()` would be sufficient for every format when using PIL. Nevertheless it seems like the unpacking format doesn't match the old format, you might want to investigate in this, or just take the advantage of using a fully powered imaging library.

Answer (score 1):

What about using struct?

```
import struct

f0 = struct.unpack('>f', f.read(4))[0]
f1 = struct.unpack('>f', f.read(4))[0]
f2 = struct.unpack('>f', f.read(4))[0]
....
```

of better in the loop

```
for i in range(0, 2580*7839):
    ff = struct.unpack('>f', f.read(4))[0]
    print(i,ff)
```

it will break somewhere and you'll know where

Comment: I do use struct. I think it is only about wrong bformat= ">%sf", but I don't know how to correct it

Comment: ok, what about trying what I proposed? You think you have array of big-endian float, so in the loop `for i in range(0,2580*7839): ff=struct.unpack('>f', f.read(4))[0]`   and then print `i` and `ff`. You'll know where it breaks